# How are the watt-second, the newton-meter and the joule different?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

The joule is $\mathrm{kg\,\ m^2/s^2}$ right?

The watt-second is $\mathrm{J/s} \times \mathrm{s}$ thus $\mathrm{J}$.

The newton-meter is $\mathrm{kg \,\ m/s^2} \times \mathrm{m}$ thus $\mathrm{kg \,\ m^2/s^2}$.

But according to wikipedia this is not necessarily equal to one joule. Why?

Comment: The units are exactly the same. It is not clear which place of Wikipedia made you believe that the units are not equal but e.g. this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_metre says that the newton meter is equivalent to joule and it is in fact sometimes used as the name of one joule, too. The different ways to write the same unit may be sometimes used to distinguish the origin of the figure - joule for general energy, newton-meter for general torque, watt-second for energy obtained by integrating power over time. But the differences are just in the presentation, not the "values".

Answer (score 3):

Newton-meters are also the units of torques / moments of forces. These vector (actually bivector, or *axial vector*) quantities are fundamentally different from scalar energy in meaning, so one names the units differently to emphasize this difference. Hence one cannot equate these different quantities, although any equation dimensionally correct.

The units *are* equal in the following sense: any change in the base units of the unit system would mean the same scaling would apply to them. This is a consequence of their dimensional equality. Thus if the kilogram and the meter were redefined so that they stand for what we now call 2 meters and 2 kilograms, all of the above units (watts, joule seconds, newton meters) would be multiplied by $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: I am sorry but one surely *may* equate the units. The different names of the units are chosen for the different contexts - energy or torque - to identify the context using the unit as well but that doesn't justify the claim that the units are different. The torque is a pseudovector but it has the same units as energy and the magnitude of the torque (the length of the vector) is a scalar just like energy, too. ... The third unit, watt-second, is *completely* identical to the energy, including the context - it just emphasizes that the energy was probably computed by integrating power over time.

Comment: @LubošMotl what about equaling action and angular momentum? Seems the same case.

Comment: Dear Alejandro, I am not saying that the action *itself* is the same thing as an angular momentum. Even two angular momenta - like the angular momentum of the Earth and of Mercury - are not equal! I am saying that the unit of the angular momentum (any angular momentum) is the same or equal to or equivalent to... the unit of the action, any action. That's why Planck's constant may be described as a quantum of the action or a quantum of the angular momentum, too. If you fix this basic mistake in your comment then indeed, it is exactly the same thing.